FileMaker script to add portal record using a Pick list from the related table layout
the FileMaker solution has a Master Detail portal on related layouts
...the relationships are Many to Many via JOIN tables
...intention is to Add a new record to a Contacts portal in Layout A (accounts)
a scripted version opens a card window of the Contacts Master Detail portal
...contact is selected, search is performed, selected contact UUID & account UUID is added to the JOIN table
...contact is not found, opens a card window to enter new contact info, Continue Button script captures Account ID and new Contact ID, both IDs are added to the JOIN table
... lots of Error Trapping
are there better ways in FileMaker to achieve the process like JSON, Let( ), or existing tools?
